# Remove crashes from Crashlytics that require a missing dsym

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I don't have the dsym and can't re-generate nor download it.

We got some crashes that were reported during development because the code which disables reporting in the dev environment was removed for a while. So I've got a bunch of crashes that require dsyms and it's impossible for me to get those dsyms. They only existed for a short period of time in between rebuilding the app 100 times per day during development.

How can I either:

1. hide/remove/disable crash reports that have missing dsyms?

or

2. hide/remove/disable all crash reports for a certain version of the app?

I've found lots of people explaining how to disable certain versions in Fabric, but Fabric is gone now and I can't find a way to do it in Crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

If you write in to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) they can disable certain versions/builds of your app. This will effectively make the missing dSYM banner go away. I can also help with this (as a Firebase Support Lead), if you want to message me your bundle ID and the version(s) you want to disable in a private thread.